# .slideUp() on complete not working

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I've created an overlay for an image when hovered over. The overlay consist of a `<div>` which an opacity covering the whole image and a small box that slides up from the bottom. Everything thing reverts back to normal when the mouse leaves the image.

This all works perfectly fine, however I'm trying to add a `complete:` callback to that the box at the bottom will only slide back down once it has completed it's first slideUp animation to prevent it from looping.

Here is what I have tried so far but it does not seem to be doing the trick:

```
$('.overlay-wrapper').mouseenter(function(){

    // variables are all set here

    overlayBottom.slideUp({

        complete: function(){

            $('.overlay-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){

                $self.find('.overlay-bottom').slideDown();

            });
        }

    });

});
```

I'm sure as to why this isn't working as I'm calling the `mouseleave` event once the `slideUp` is complete.

Here is a JSFiddle mockup for a live preview:

http://jsfiddle.net/8HnPb/1/

Can someone please shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so people can test on there? I think you can use `.stop()` instead of waiting for the animation but hard to say without seeing some code

Comment: @Huangism - I've added a Fiddle link to the question

Comment: Have you implemented what @Huangism suggested? Adding stops. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/8HnPb/2/

Comment: @Lodder http://jsfiddle.net/8HnPb/3/ is this what you want, or what you want to avoid?

Comment: @Huangism - That's perfect. works great. Please feel free to write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following http://jsfiddle.net/8HnPb/3

```
$('.overlay-wrapper').mouseenter(function(){

    var $self = $(this);
    var overlay = $self.find('.overlay');
    var overlayBottom = $self.find('.overlay-bottom');
    var imageWidth = $self.find('img').width();

    overlay.stop().removeClass('active', 200).width(imageWidth);
    overlayBottom.slideDown();
    overlayBottom.width(imageWidth);

}); 

$('.overlay-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.find('.overlay').stop().removeClass('active', 200);
    $self.find('.overlay-bottom').stop(true, false).slideUp('fast');
});
```

I move the mouseleave out of the complete and added stop so it will not loop. So now if your mouse leaves the image box, the slideup will stop, then slide down from whatever position it stopped at.

For more info on `.stop()` http://api.jquery.com/stop/